How to approximate a 90 degrees sine with a bezier curve in PostScript
I have found here similar questions for other languages like SVG but they don't quite answer this particular question.
I want to find a good approximation of the first 90 degrees of a sine curve with bezier in postscript. I have found the full 360 curve, I tried to subdivide it using a known algorithm but the result is not exactly 90 degrees. Then by try and error I got something acceptable (blue curve over the red one) but when I scale it horizontally, it doesn't fit with the sine curve (black curve) so I am confuse about if a scalable bezier approximation is possible.

This is the PostScript code:
1 0 0 setrgbcolor

% Full 360 degree period curve
0 0  moveto
0.4673 3.4641 0.5327 -3.4641 1 0 curveto
stroke

% 90 degree aprox
0 0 1 setrgbcolor
0 0 moveto
0.116825 0.866025 0.20 1.0  0.25 1 curveto
stroke

% Same as above but scaled 4x horizontally
0 0  moveto
0.4673 0.866025  0.8 1  1 1 curveto
stroke

I will appreciate any hint.

After exploring closer, the wrong curve turns to be the blue one, created after the answer to this question in the math community:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235124/getting-the-most-accurate-bezier-curve-that-plots-a-sine-wave
Although it is possible to approximate the whole sine period with a single bezier segment, it is not recommended and there is nothing wrong to use two segments, as recommended in the following link:
http://www.telegraphics.net/sw/info/sinehow.html
That's what I did so I considere this question solved.
